# http.request events do not fire after CONNECT event

Tags: node.js, sockets, http

I have a scenario where I need to build a web socket client. The client needs to first make a CONNECT request through an HTTP proxy. Once connected, I manually write on the socket to upgrade the connection. In Wireshark, I see the server response successfully upgrades the connection, but my `req.on('upgrade')` event never fires! I've looked at piping the `conn` socket back to `req`, but I just can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

```
var http = require('http');

// make a request
var options = {
    port:8080,
    host:'http.proxy.com',
    path: 'echo.websocket.org:80',
    headers: {
        'Host': 'echo.websocket.org',
        'Proxy-Connection':'keep-alive'
    },
    method: 'CONNECT'
};

var req = http.request(options);
req.end();

req.on('connect', function(res, conn, connectHead) {
    console.log('connected');
    // manually request Web Socket upgrade
    conn.write('GET /?encoding=text HTTP/1.1\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nHost: echo.websocket.org\r\nOrigin: http://www.websocket.org\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36\r\n\r\n');    
});

// this event never fires!
req.on('upgrade', function (res, socket, upgradeHead) {
    console.log('got upgraded!');
    socket.write('test');
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('req on data');
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel and websockets are still **not** stable. Use something like `socket.io` or other websocket library.

Comment: +1 for `reinventing the wheel`